# Typescript exclude methods from class once invoked

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, ecmascript-next

I have a use case where I want to exclude methods from return type of class method once they are invoked. ie, let us assume I have a class `Setup` having method `step1`, `step2` and `step3`.

```
class Setup {

    step1() {
        return this;
    }
    
    step2() { 
        return this;
    }
    
    step3() { 
        return this;
    }
}

let setup = new Setup();
```

My use case

1. is once `step1` is invoked it should return an instance of Setup which does not have `step1` method at all, and users should only get the option to select between `step2` and `step3` and once `step2` is invoked it should only get `step3`, as `step1` and `step2` were already invoked, so that a better DX can be provided
2. The order of execution does not matter, ie, someone can execute `step3` before they execute `step1`.
3. And also, I am seeking the solution to work during runtime, ie during runtime, a step once invoked should be available for invocation itself.

```
let setup = new Setup();

setup
    .step1()
    .step2()
    .step1(); // This should not be possible as step 1 was already invoked
```

I have already tried this, but after invoking `step2` it shows `step1` as an option again. I am aware that this is partially due to Omit taking `Setup` as the type from which it should exclude the key. But, I am unable to find a way to refer the current instance and exclude the current method.

```
export type Omit<A extends object, K extends string> = Pick<A, Exclude<keyof A, K>>

class Setup {

    step1(): Omit<Setup, 'step1'> {
        return this;
    }
    
    step2(): Omit<Setup, 'step2'>{ 
        return this;
    }
    
    step3():Omit<Setup, 'step3'>{ 
        return this;
    }
}

let setup = new Setup();
```

Comment: Omit is just a typescript type. It doesn't have any effect on the transpiled javascript.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgvDMW) meet your needs? If so, I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: In case it matters, [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WYeLbW) is the closest I can get both at compile time and at runtime. If you want to see an answer written up about it I suppose I can, but if the other answer here is sufficient for you I probably won't bother. Let me know.

Comment: Wait, should you be allowed to write `s.step2().step3().step1()`?  Or is the order strictly `s.step1().step2().step3()`?  If it's the latter then classes are really not what you want here; just return a nested object like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnElVw).  Is that what you're looking for? Let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz I think the second solution you gave works!!! as I can see it will be excluded during runtime as well.. Could you help me understand the solution from Typescript perspective??

I think I understood from JS perspective..

I will have to play around once to see what we will be the return type..

Comment: "I will have to play around once to see what we will be the return type" If you're not sure whether my suggestion works for you, then I will wait until you're sure. But: I think you should either do it in the type system or at runtime but not both. Is the code consuming `Setup` all written in TypeScript? Then there is no reason to worry about whether the method exists at runtime. Or will there be non-TS code at runtime calling it? Then you should just harden at runtime and not worry much about stronger types. But I'm happy to explain both *if* my suggestion meets your needs. Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz I am happy to accept your answer.. the code can be non TS during runtime as well..

Comment: @jcalz could you hlpe me understand the purpose of `K extends string = never` I am unable to quite understand this

Comment: I've answered and hopefully explained the `= never` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want both the TypeScript to issue a compiler warning if someone tries to call a method more than once in their TypeScript code, *and* you want a runtime error if someone tries to call a method more than once at runtime.  These goals are more or less independent, and you'll have to spend effort doing each one separately.  It would be nice if you could just write the code that enforces your constraint at runtime and the compiler could just inspect that and behave accordingly at compile time... but the compiler's just not smart enough to do that.  So in what follows let's look at each part separately.

---

First the type system:

```
type OmitSetup<K extends string> = Omit<Setup<K>, K>;
declare class Setup<K extends string = never> {
  step1(): OmitSetup<K | "step1">;
  step2(): OmitSetup<K | "step2">;
  step3(): OmitSetup<K | "step3">;
}
```

The idea is to make the `Setup` class [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the `string`-[constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) type parameter `K` corresponding to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of method names that should be suppressed.  The [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) is `never` (`K = never`) because when you first create a `Setup` you haven't suppressed any method names.

Also, since you have `step1`, `step2`, and `step3` methods declared in `Setup<K>`, those methods will be present on `Setup<K>` no matter what `K` is.  That's why I defined `OmitSetup<K>`, which gives you a view into `Setup<K>` without the methods, using [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys), and so every time you call a method with name `N`, the compiler returns `OmitSetup<K | N>`, adding `N` to the list of names to suppress.

Let's walk though how it works at compile time:

```
const s = new Setup();
// const s: Setup<never>
const s1 = s.step1();
// const s1: OmitSetup<"step1">
const s12 = s1.step2();
// const s12: OmitSetup<"step1" | "step2">
const s123 = s12.step3();
// const s123: OmitSetup<"step1" | "step2" | "step3">
```

So `s` is a `Setup<never>` with nothing suppressed; when we call `step1()` it returns an `OmitSetup<"step1">`, which does not have a known `step1` property.  If you call `step2()` on that, you get an `OmitSetup<"step1" | "step2">`, leaving you with something that only has a known `step3` method.  When you call that method, you get an `OmitSetup<"step1" | "step2" | "step3">`, and thus all the methods are suppressed.

That gives you the desired behavior:

```
s.step1().step2().step3(); // okay
s.step2().step1().step3(); // okay
s.step1().step2().step1(); // error!
// -------------> ~~~~~
// Property 'step1' does not exist on type 'OmitSetup<"step1" | "step2">'. 
// Did you mean 'step3'?
```

---

Then at runtime:

```
class Setup {
  step1() {
    console.log("step1");
    return Object.assign(new Setup(), this, { step1: undefined });
  }
  step2() {
    console.log("step2");
    return Object.assign(new Setup(), this, { step2: undefined });
  }
  step3() {
    console.log("step3");
    return Object.assign(new Setup(), this, { step3: undefined });
  }
}
```

Here each method returns a new object (this lets us re-use existing values without mutating their states, so you can write `s.step1()` a million times, because `s` never changes, but you can never write `s.step1().step1()`).  The new object copies all the properties from the current one, and also explicitly sets the property corresponding to the current method to `undefined`, so that nobody can call it at runtime.  Let's test it out:

```
const s = new Setup();
s.step1().step2().step3(); // "step1", "step2", "step3"
s.step2().step1().step3(); // "step2", "step1", "step3"
s.step1().step2().step1(); // "step1", "step2", RUNTIME ERROR!
// s.step1().step2().step1 is not a function
```

Looks good; you can call the three methods in any order, but if you try to call the same method twice you get a runtime error.

---

Finally, we can marry the types to the runtime code in a single TypeScript file like this:

```
type OmitSetup<K extends string> = Omit<Setup<K>, K>;
class Setup<K extends string = never> {
  step1(): OmitSetup<K | "step1"> {
    console.log("step1");
    return Object.assign(new Setup(), this, { step1: undefined }) as any
  }
  step2(): OmitSetup<K | "step2"> {
    console.log("step2");
    return Object.assign(new Setup(), this, { step2: undefined }) as any
  }
  step3(): OmitSetup<K | "step3"> {
    console.log("step3");
    return Object.assign(new Setup(), this, { step3: undefined }) as any
  }
};
```

This is mostly just [annotating the method return types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) as well as [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) the values returned as [the intentionally loose `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  You actually don't need `as any` here to get it to compile, but I've included it to make it obvious to the reader that the implementation and the typings are independent.  The compiler can't understand that `Object.assign(new Setup(), this, { step3: undefined })` is of type `OmitSetup<K | "step3">` so we are telling it not to worry.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgCoCeMEA8sBlXoUUgC43J1gCW7AZQjsArjAA8AaSQQAHuwjAAJlCRR2AJ17AA5gD4kAXiQ9+4oaImS9AGiTWA3KyJKI8DCA3J3IKKotiUjLyiipqmto6RsQQAG4QGgYEbGzqEDAAjAAUAJQAXCZ8gsKB0gA+SABEaZmVek4pRDUATLkFpsWWQRXVCjDNdQ2NNQDMbYX8AVZIPaODzkgAvvgL8AD2wOpq0cAQAO5IU7lDRAD0p0jrm+xqBVPiu-GJqxtbUBnRUAB0Ndk5J0hzpdXjd3u0ivdeukMnUXtc1Blmp8Mj8+q1-gsgVc3ojwZMShIobUZlUWrCUtjQYiRsjmqj0mMMSksSCEc0RnjOoEiTCSUSBny5noVilvr9cvT+hLRsdARc1gBrEBUBZitHSvp-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-GeYJbCYSJuHifht73tJz4EvJH5fng1EZCp9FqUssG+EgtYqgurGiklS0jTmEXrZxC7cUhfGoftRCHcex0SQR50GVdr4KbdP4tI9DGgS972qB982adBPnjBm-2zD5QP40QoO8ShAkaVDwkw2JcNnURMkvuRqPURySAAU9jHY29eNfVpThwm802XaRGL+SZZnOa5QLWat-ReSrvmy1KyWZArlkq5FKswuFLl+aKCXy9rfy6krYX62rMVxcZOva+ZvypaowDxu9WU5QO+XMk6bpB46nreh6voBmsQYhuGmqRtGsaewmshJjcKY1cgoYk1024A6rej5kgJZlhWVY1nWscMk2BX4IsQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

Now that you've said the aim is to not have the function itself, you can just reassign it to `undefined` so there actually is no function.

On top of it, you can also have Typescript inference by correctly excluding multiple types.

```
class Setup {
    step1(): Omit<Setup, 'step1'> {
        (this as any).step1 = undefined;
        return this;
    }
    
    step2(): Omit<Setup, 'step1' | 'step2'> { 
        return this;
    }
    
    step3(): Omit<Setup, 'step1' | 'step2' | 'step3'> { 
        return this;
    }
}
```

This way, the `step1` is actually deleted and cannot be called and will throw `TypeError step1 is undefined` and Typescript will correctly show `step2`, `step3` alone.

Comment: This is kind of a weird take; perhaps someone should do this at runtime and *also* get the compiler to be aware of the constraint to help programmers avoid the problem in the first place.  And if they did do that, then there might not be a runtime need (since the whole point of the type system is to help prevent errors which would otherwise need runtime checks... or else `function foo(x: string) {x.toUpperCase()}` is just "patched up via the type system" and the "robust" solution is `function foo(x: unknown) {if (typeof x === "string") {x.toUpperCase()}}`, but nobody would suggest that).

Comment: @jcalz OP doesn't state if he's also handling it within the business logic. One can do the (`as <Type>`) shenanigans and call it and without actual business logic preventing it. Having Typescript reflect that decision is great but it shouldn't be the sole enforcer for a sequence of steps which might business critical. I'll edit my answer to state on top getting it done via TS, it should actually be prevented in code as well.

Comment: @AmitJoki You are correct I want it to be dealt in both typescript and pure JS way.. The aim is to not have the function itself.. from what is being returned rather than restricting the execution of the function..

Comment:  Oh well, I guess I'll bow out then!  I mistakenly thought the ask was to do it as a developer aid and not necessarily at runtime.

Comment: @AmitJoki The order of calling does not matter. someone can call `step2` before `step1`.


@j

Comment: @jcalz Awesome the solution you gave works for typescript, and solves one purpose that is developer aid..

But I am also looking for something during runtime..  I can accept your solution partially.. :)